# Unable to change the value of enum field in MySQL when manually typing a query

Tags: mysql, enums

I have an `enum` column in a MySQL table called `site_status`:

[image]

From my understanding, updating the value of such a field is exactly the same process as changing value of a `varchar` or `int` or any other field.

The only *"limitation"* is that as a value I obviously have to set one from predefined values - as this is the nature of `enum` types. Right?

So I want to change `site_status` from `LIVE` to `FREE`:

I type:

```
update db_name.db_table set site_status = 'FREE' where site_id = 501;
```

Pretty easy query. Unfortunately does nothing. It also doesn't produce any error. Simply:

> 0 rows affected.

What am I doing wrong? When I manually click via GUI in Sequel Pro, the value is changed to `FREE` with no issues. I see a dropdown from which I pick another option.

Comment: What happens if you `select *` for that `site_id`?

Comment: I'm getting a typical, single row with `site_id` equal to `501` like: `select * from db_name.db_table where site_id = 501;` So no issues with select statement.

Comment: And the `ENUM` value isn't already equal to what you're setting it?

Comment: No. This is the case to reproduce the issue. 1) I manually revert `site_status` to `LIVE`. 2) I check - it's `LIVE` 3) I call update query 4) 0 rows affected 5) I call `select * (…)` to double check) 6) It's still `LIVE`.

@ManojShukla I use GUI Sequel Pro in macOS.

Comment: yes @slick I noticed that so deleted my comment. sorry about that.

Comment: I wonder who gave -1 since the question is shaped in a pretty clear way… Weird issue so I ask SO community…

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not leaving `db_name.db_table` in the update statement, correct? (Sorry if that sounds stupid, but I've seen it before so I have to check)

Comment: just give this a try: `update db_name.db_table set db_name.db_table.site_status = 'PENDING' where db_name.db_table.site_id = 502;` just to be sure it is not restricting you on other row with different values.